# Html5, JavaScript, Canvas Animations?

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas, timing

I've a watch "second hand" image need to move it every second. if I use the canvas I'll delete the canvas each second so, it'll be ugly to load the watch photo and the "second hand" photo.

I need help.

Comment: Then don't put the watch photo in the canvas, draw the canvas over it.

Comment: I haven't code, I just have the idea and I can't implement it, really need help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use layers... To draw only the part which is moving.
There is a great tutorial at this address :
http://arc.id.au/CanvasLayers.html

Quote from this website :

> The traditional animation technique is to use a stack of transparent layers overlaying a background image, with the items to be animated each being drawn on a separate layer. Only the layers that change on each frame are redrawn and the other layers are left unchanged. The graphics engine can sort out the exposed areas to be redrawn from underlying layers without user code being required.

Answer (score 0):

One (somewhat) easy way to do it is to use two canvases.

<canvas id="foregroundCanvas"></canvas>
<canvas id="backgroundCanvas"></canvas>

Here is a great tutorial on w3schools:
http://www.w3schools.com/canvas/canvas_clock_start.asp
The following is the code from the link.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"
style="background-color:#333">
</canvas>

<script>
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var radius = canvas.height / 2;
ctx.translate(radius, radius);
radius = radius * 0.90
setInterval(drawClock, 1000);

function drawClock() {
  drawFace(ctx, radius);
  drawNumbers(ctx, radius);
  drawTime(ctx, radius);
}

function drawFace(ctx, radius) {
  var grad;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(0, 0, radius, 0, 2*Math.PI);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
  ctx.fill();
  grad = ctx.createRadialGradient(0,0,radius*0.95, 0,0,radius*1.05);
  grad.addColorStop(0, '#333');
  grad.addColorStop(0.5, 'white');
  grad.addColorStop(1, '#333');
  ctx.strokeStyle = grad;
  ctx.lineWidth = radius*0.1;
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(0, 0, radius*0.1, 0, 2*Math.PI);
  ctx.fillStyle = '#333';
  ctx.fill();
}

function drawNumbers(ctx, radius) {
  var ang;
  var num;
  ctx.font = radius*0.15 + "px arial";
  ctx.textBaseline="middle";
  ctx.textAlign="center";
  for(num = 1; num < 13; num++){
    ang = num * Math.PI / 6;
    ctx.rotate(ang);
    ctx.translate(0, -radius*0.85);
    ctx.rotate(-ang);
    ctx.fillText(num.toString(), 0, 0);
    ctx.rotate(ang);
    ctx.translate(0, radius*0.85);
    ctx.rotate(-ang);
  }
}

function drawTime(ctx, radius){
    var now = new Date();
    var hour = now.getHours();
    var minute = now.getMinutes();
    var second = now.getSeconds();
    //hour
    hour=hour%12;
    hour=(hour*Math.PI/6)+
    (minute*Math.PI/(6*60))+
    (second*Math.PI/(360*60));
    drawHand(ctx, hour, radius*0.5, radius*0.07);
    //minute
    minute=(minute*Math.PI/30)+(second*Math.PI/(30*60));
    drawHand(ctx, minute, radius*0.8, radius*0.07);
    // second
    second=(second*Math.PI/30);
    drawHand(ctx, second, radius*0.9, radius*0.02);
}

function drawHand(ctx, pos, length, width) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineWidth = width;
    ctx.lineCap = "round";
    ctx.moveTo(0,0);
    ctx.rotate(pos);
    ctx.lineTo(0, -length);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.rotate(-pos);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```